# bash loop through list of strings

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian

Is it possible to format this sample:

```
for i in string1 string2 stringN
do
 echo $i
done
```

to something similar to this:

```
for i in 
string1
string2
stringN
do
 echo $i
done
```

EDIT: Sorry for confusion, didn't realize that there was different methods of executing script - sh `<scriptname>` versus `bash <scriptname>` and also this thing which I cannot name right now - `#!/bin/sh` and `#!/bin/bash` :)

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Did you try what you're asking to see whether it'd work?

Comment: @Jesse_b readability and managebility of bunch of strings

Comment: @DopeGhoti yes I did

Comment: @waayee:  In that case an array is your best bet.  See Glenn Jackman's answer.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Using arrays in bash can aid readability: this array syntax allows arbitrary whitespace between words.

```
strings=(
    string1
    string2
    "string with spaces"
    stringN
)
for i in "${strings[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: This seems most elegant, but unfortunately gives error: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: @waayee, then you're not running it in Bash. Remember that `sh` isn't necessarily Bash, and especially isn't on Debian and Ubuntu.

Comment: @ilkkachu Think I get it now - must run "bash <scriptname>" not "sh <scriptname>" :)

Comment: @waayee, or put a proper hashbang/shebang line and run it like an executable. Required reading: [Does the shebang determine the shell which runs the script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87560/does-the-shebang-determine-the-shell-which-runs-the-script)

Comment: @glennjackman: what does the `@` do? If I wanted "${strings[@]}" to be separated by commas instead of spaces, is it easy to do that?

Comment: @rrrrr, your questions are probably answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12314451/7552

Comment: Syntax error "( unexpected"

Comment: Read the other comments - that error has already been discussed.

Answer (score 10):

You can escape the linebreak with a backslash:

```
$ for i in \
> hello \
> world
> do
> echo $i
> done
hello
world
$
```

Answer (score 6):

```
list='a b c d'
for element in $list;do 
    echo "$element"
done
```

Comment: You are missing semicolons!

Comment: Note that this would work as long as each string is a separate word. As soon as you have spaces in your strings, the spaces would break the string apart into multiple words.  Also, if the `$list` string contains filename globbing characters (`list='* * * *'`), the shell would potentially replace these with matching filenames.

Answer (score 4):

You may escape the newlines before/after each item that you loop over:

```
for i in \
    string1 \
    string2 \
    stringN
do
   printf '%s\n' "$i"
done
```

Or, for this simple example:

```
printf '%s\n' string1 string2 stringN
```

which has the same result.

Related:

- [Why do I need to place “do” in the same line as “for”?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/443507)

Variation using a `bash` array:

```
strings=(
    string1
    string2
    stringN
)

printf '%s\n' "${strings[@]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

If switching to `zsh` is an option:

```
for string (
  string1
  'other string'
  etc..
) printf '%s\n' "$string"
```

Answer (score 1):

Same thing, less text:

```
array=(
        string{1..7}
)

for i in "${array[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: `string1` etc. aren’t the literal values to be displayed, they’re placeholders, so this approach doesn’t work.

Comment: if so, why bothering `array ( … )`? just do `for i in string{1..7}; do     echo "$i"; done`; even `printf '%s\n' string{1..7}`

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over a list of strings (with and without embedded spaces) as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

var1="text-without-spaces"
var2="text with spaces"

for item in "${var1}" "${var2}" "more-without-spaces" "more with spaces"; do
    echo "'${item}'"
done
```

NB You can leave out braces around variable identifiers in the above example e.g. use `$var1` instead of `${var1}`.

This outputs:

> 'text-without-spaces'
> 'text with spaces'
> 'more-without-spaces'
> 'more with spaces'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `loop` command, available [here](https://github.com/Miserlou/Loop), like so:

```
$ loop 'echo "$ITEM"' --for string1,string2,string3
```

or, if you have the list in a file, one per line:

```
$ <file_list.txt loop 'echo "$ITEM"'
```

Beware however that it runs one `sh` invocation per item (to interpret that code whilst the item is stored in the `ITEM` environment variable), and that it currently chokes on sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters in UTF-8 (even if the locale's charmap is not UTF-8).