# What's wrong with putting do on the same line as for?

Tags: shell-script, portability

While reading about [11.12 Limitations of Shell Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.66/html_node/Limitations-of-Builtins.html#for) I came across the following:

> To loop over positional arguments, use:
>
> > ```
> > for arg
> > do
> >    echo "$arg"
> > done
> > ```
>
> You may not leave the do on the same line as for, since some shells improperly grok:
>
> > ```
> > for arg; do
> >    echo "$arg"
> > done
> > ```

---

It doesn't seem to explain anymore detail than that.

#### Questions

- What shells have a problem with this syntax?
- What is the problem?

Comment: Certainly not any of the usual suspects; this works fine with `bash`, `dash`, `sh`, `fish`, and `zsh` which are the only shells I have installed at the moment.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/443507/why-do-i-need-to-place-do-in-the-same-line-as-for